# Limiting image upload to jpg in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm still new to Asp .Net MVC, and C#. I'm experiencing with learning how to do certain things and I'm running into a problem with getting the button to load my view. I learned that I don't need an event listener like I normally would in .NET MVC, so I used @Ajax.ActionLink for my button. However, when I click on my button it doesn't load my view. I can't figure out why? I can't make the button load my view.

Here's what I have done. In my shared folder, I have a layout page that will include a button. I inserted this button:

```
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Res-TestImageExtension","TestImageExtension","TestImageExtension","",App.ViewOptions.appAjaxOptions,App.ViewOptions.blueButtonHtmlAttributes)</li>
```

In my controller folder I have inserted a controller with the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HexaPod.Controllers
{

public class TestImageExtensionController : Controller
{
// For multiple file select
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(List<HttpPostedFileBase> image)
    {

        if (image != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in image)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"),   Path.GetFileName(item.FileName));
                item.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }

        return PartialView("TestImageExtension");
    }

}
```

}

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HexaPod.Models
{
public partial class ImageUpload {
  public int ID { get; set;} 

  public string ImagePath {get; set;} 
}
}
```

View:

```
@model HexaPod.Models.ImageUpload

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Image Upload";
}

@*

*@
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =  
"multipart/form-data", id = "frm_profile" }))
{
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath, new { type = "file", accept = "image/jpeg,  image/jpg"}) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath)
// for multiple file select
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath, new { type = "file", accept = "image/jpeg,   image/jpg", multiple = "multiple" })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

My method name is  Create() but I didn't word my method correctly in @Ajax.ActionLink(). "TestImageExtension" should have been "Create" for the second string. Button renders partialview now.